# ping: Name or service not known

Tags: linux, ping, strace

**Problem**

```
ping: service.sys-dev.company.com: Name or service not known
```

host, nslookup and dig works

```
# host service.sys-dev.company.com
traefik-proxy.ingresscontrollers.svc.cluster.local has address 10.0.60.226
```

**Details**

Coredns zone

```
sys-dev.company.com:53 {
errors
log
ready
health
rewrite name regex (.*)\.sys-dev\.company\.com traefik-proxy.ingresscontrollers.svc.cluster.local
kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
  pods insecure
  fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
}
prometheus :9153
forward . /etc/resolv.conf
cache 30
loop
reload
loadbalance
}
```

```
# dig @10.0.0.10  service.sys-dev.company.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.19-1~deb12u1-Debian <<>> @10.0.0.10 service.sys-dev.company.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27146
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 9ea30e2a15ac33b7 (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;service.sys-dev.company.com. IN        A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
traefik-proxy.ingresscontrollers.svc.cluster.local. 5 IN A 10.0.60.226

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.10#53(10.0.0.10) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 08 14:15:48 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 139
```

I found a difference in the strace that I would like someone to explain. I have two containers and this command behaves differently in them.

- The settings of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and `resolv.conf` are the same.

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`

```
search xxx.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local m3ked1pts4futor0jcy3sg2y4d.ax.internal.cloudapp.net
nameserver 10.0.0.10
options ndots:5
```

---

**OK**

*LSB:* Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.142.82.26    dotnet8
```

[Full strace](https://pastebin.pl/view/146f6209)

Here you can see that the last `connect` call already contains the IP

```
3095  connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.10")}, 16) = 0
3095  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
3095  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
3095  recvfrom(5, "\273y\205\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\vservice\tsys-dev\6company\3com\0\0\34\0\1\7cluster\5local\0\0\6\0\1\0\0\0\5\0D\2ns\3dns\7cluster\5local\0\nhostmaster\7cluster\5local\0e\234\0\30\0\0\34 \0\0\7\10\0\1Q\200\0\0\0\5", 2048, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.10")}, [28 => 16]) = 143
3095  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4997) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
3095  recvfrom(5, "o\7\205\0\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\vservice\tsys-dev\6company\3com\0\0\1\0\1\rtraefik-proxy\22ingresscontrollers\3svc\7cluster\5local\0\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\5\0\4\n\0<\342", 65536, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.10")}, [28 => 16]) = 116
3095  connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(1025), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.60.226")}, 16) = 0
```

```
PING traefik-proxy.ingresscontrollers.svc.cluster.local (10.0.60.226) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

**NOK**

*LSB:* Debian GNU/Linux 12

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.142.83.141   dotnet8-test
```

[Full strace](https://pastebin.pl/view/50643621)

```
1153  connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.10")}, 16) = 0
1153  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
1153  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
1153  recvfrom(5, "\211\226\205\0\0\1\0\0\0\1\0\0\vservice\tsys-dev\6company\3com\0\0\34\0\1\7cluster\5local\0\0\6\0\1\0\0\0\5\0D\2ns\3dns\7cluster\5local\0\nhostmaster\7cluster\5local\0e\233\377\316\0\0\34 \0\0\7\10\0\1Q\200\0\0\0\5", 2048, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.10")}, [28 => 16]) = 143
1153  poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 4997) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
1153  recvfrom(5, "|\227\205\0\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\vservice\tsys-dev\6company\3com\0\0\1\0\1\rtraefik-proxy\22ingresscontrollers\3svc\7cluster\5local\0\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\5\0\4\n\0<\342", 65536, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.10")}, [28 => 16]) = 116
```

After the last `recvfrom` call there is only

```
1186  close(5)                          = 0
1186  write(2, "ping: ", 6)             = 6
1186  write(2, "service.sys-dev.company.com: Name or service not known", 59) = 59
1186  write(2, "\n", 1)                 = 1
1186  close(1)                          = 0
1186  close(2)                          = 0
1186  exit_group(2)                     = ?
1186  +++ exited with 2 +++
```

```
ping: service.sys-dev.company.com: Name or service not known
```

I am very interested in why the behaviour is different and I will be glad if someone can help me to clarify or direct me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think your issue is related to this : https://superuser.com/a/1417265/1875547

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04.3, the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file is like : `hosts: files dns` - In Debian 12, the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is like : `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname`- In Ubuntu, you reach the DNS server, in Debian, you don't. - So the `ping` does not work because it uses `nsswitch` file to resolve names, the `host` command uses directly the `resolv.conf` file.

Comment: I also added `nsswitch.conf`. They are identical and contain `hosts: dns files`.

Comment: Do you have this behavior with all names ? Or only this one ? - With a special domain (.local) ?

Comment: Furthermore, Ubuntu uses `systemd-resolved` service as default for DNS resolver, do you have something in the file : `/etc/systemd/resolver.conf` ? - What do you have inside both `/etc/resolver.conf` ? Thanks.

Comment: Both `/etc/resolver.conf` files are also identical, but I have added its contents for clarity. The Ubuntu container does not contain the `/etc/systemd/resolver.conf` file.  Everything works as it should in Ubuntu - the problem is with Debian GNU/Linux 12 container. As far as DNS is concerned, I can translate google.com and others without a problem - the problem is with our domain, which for security reasons I replaced with company.com. But all FQDNs can be resolved from the second container.

Comment: Yes sorry, the file is `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`, I did a mistake in my previous message, but it does not matter in that case.

Comment: There is no such file in the Ubuntu container.

Comment: Can you try by removing (comment) the `options ndots:5` in `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: Commented. But the problem still persists.

Comment: What is the nameserver at 10.0.0.10? It is clearly insane, because your straces show, and your dig (more conveniently) confirms, it is serving an 'answer' A RR that is not for the 'question' name or a CNAME thereof, and thus not an answer. I believe Debian is right to ignore it, and I don't know why Ubuntu uses it, unless the CNAME actually exists somewhere else and is cached somehow -- but I don't see how with your configs. Can you start a new Ubuntu container (or restart this one, if that's not too disruptive) and see if it still works?

Comment: There is a coredns at that address. In his log can be seen nicely for both instances (Ubuntu and Debian) that the query response is correctly handled. Likewise wireshark shows that the query goes to 10.0.0.10 and is returned with the correct data = this is only confirmed by the strace of the recvfrom call, where you can see traefik-proxy.ingresscontrollers.svc.cluster.local. I killed and recreated the container - nothing changed.

Comment: I also tried to create another one instead of Ubuntu, where it works, and it is also Debian (same version) and there is the same problem. That is, it currently works only from Ubuntu.

Comment: Alpine image behaves the same as Debian. I have added the part of the coredns configuration where the *.sys-dev.company.com is overwritten by traefik-proxy.ingresscontrollers.svc.cluster.local.

Comment: Now I came across https://github.com/coredns/coredns/tree/master/plugin/rewrite#explicit-response-name-rewrite. Maybe that's what I need?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Is there any documentation somewhere that explains what you wrote about the question and answer (that they should be identical)? I'd be interested in the details of why this happens and why different OSes behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the difference between the `ANSWER` and `QUESTION` sections. The following modification is required to be used with CoreDNS:

https://github.com/coredns/coredns/discussions/6460

```
rewrite stop {
        name regex service.sys-dev.company.com traefik-proxy.ingresscontrollers.svc.cluster.local
        answer auto
    }
```

**Explanation**: https://github.com/coredns/coredns/tree/master/plugin/rewrite#response-rewrites

> When rewriting incoming DNS requests' names (field name), CoreDNS
> re-writes the QUESTION SECTION section of the requests. It may be
> necessary to rewrite the ANSWER SECTION of the requests, **because
> some DNS resolvers treat mismatches between the QUESTION SECTION and
> ANSWER SECTION as a man-in-the-middle attack (MITM)**.

The tests showed that for curl/dotnet in combination with Debian/Alpine it requires this match to work properly. Difference between the `ANSWER` and the `QUESTION`, it evaluates it as a negative and non-existent record.